# i'm new to scala. can somebody tell me why i'm getting a error illicit start of simple function when writing the def recur function

Tags: scala

```
def fact(n: Int) = products(x => x)(1,n)

fact(5)

def mapReduce(f: Int => Int, combine: (Int, Int) => Int, zero: Int)(a:Int,b:Int): Int = 
    def recur(a: Int): Int =
        if(a>b) zero
        else combine(f(a),recur(a+1))
    recur(a) 

def sum(f: Int => Int) = mapReduce(f, (x, y) => x+y, 0)
def products(f: Int => Int) = mapReduce(f, (x, y) => x*y, 1) 
sum(fact)(1,5)
products(fact)(1,5)
```

Comment: Can you please format your question and include more details.

Comment: including compiler's error would be great.. and welcome to SO.

Comment: /* 
* this code is written in worksheet type of scala file, I'm not running the file, the error is shown by the vs code 
* the error is  "illicit start of simple expression"
* when i put everything after the mapReduce function in{} braces the error is shown when i'm trying to call the mapReduce Function.
*/

Comment: I would guess the indentation based syntax doesn't support nested `defs` try with braces for `mapReduce`

Comment: [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MDQWTpuBSHuk3gEa35jbKw) finds no problems.

Comment: It's definitly running on scastie. but not on vs studio. any particular reason? @jwvh

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez If I'm adding braces then this error is resolved but a new error arise in the sum and product functions which goes on as error - "missing argument list for method mapReduce in object y
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `mapReduce _` or `mapReduce(_,_,_)(_,_)` instead of `mapReduce`.
    def sum(f: Int => Int) = mapReduce(f, (x, y) => x+y, 0)"

Comment: By best practice and to save head aches use explicit return types for all methods and public values; you will see that it helps. - Also, it would be good to follow a tutorial / course that guides you through the language.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez and yes I'm following a course on this and that course made me confused as it had a code working without the return type. I'll remember to use explicit return types for all methods and public values. The problem is solved Thanks alot to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def mapReduce(f: Int => Int, combine: (Int, Int) => Int, zero: Int)(a:Int,b:Int): Int = {
  def recur(a: Int): Int =
    if (a > b) zero
    else combine(f(a), recur(a + 1))

  recur(a)
}

def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = mapReduce(f, (x, y) => x+y, 0)
def products(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = mapReduce(f, (x, y) => x*y, 1)
def fact(n: Int) = products(x => x)(1,n)

fact(5)
sum(fact)(1,5)
products(fact)(1,5)
```

I tried it using scala 2.13 on a scala worksheet, here curly brackets are needed for mapReduce as it contains two expressions one is a function definition and another a function invocation. Secondly when methods that returns functions such as sum and products the return type need to be specified. But I wasn't able to reproduce the error that you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot Looks like I was not providing the braces and when i did i was not mentioning  the return type  to sum and product functions which resulted in the error.